# Session Elevation options when using Federated Authentication

Tags: powershell-extensions

When I want to excecute a powerhsel Script in sitecore 9 update 2 with SPE 5 I get the following authentication Dialog.

[image]

But I am using Azure Federated Authentication Login to log in into sitecore.

And here I am not able to choose another account or Username and when I try to enter the right password for my account nothing happens. Is there a way to configure SPE so that I can use Azure Authentication?

Comment: No. You have to disable elevation.